# How can I get a list of data frames based on pattern in the middle of the data frame name?

Tags: r, list

I have many similarly named data frames and I want to put them into a list.

The data frames have names such as "df1b", "df10b", "df273b" etcetera. The middle part of the data frame name always consist of digits.

I have a partial solution but it is flawed. I want the list to consist of all data frames starting with "df" and ending with "b". I have tried this solution.

```
list <- mget(ls(pattern = "df.b"))
```

However this solution only works for names with one digit between "df" and "b". How can I modify the code to work for any number of numerical characters between "df" and "b"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try

```
list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+b$"))
```

This would get all the objects which start with `df` have a number in between and ends with `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^df[0-9]+b$"))
```

Note that `pattern` contains a regular expression:

- `^df` means that you want elements which start with df.
- `[0-9]+` means that there should be at least one digit (`+` means "one or more")
- `b$` means that it should end with a `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
list <- mget(ls(pattern = "df.*b"))
```